# Automating Interaction with website - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I'm trying to automate logging in and posting some stuff on a website, but I can't use Mechanize since there are many javascript actions involved. I was wondering if there were any other gems/tools to use that support javascript.

I tried Watir as well, but it involves having a browser, and I would like a browser-less option.

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options:

- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)
- [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)
- [Selenium webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.html#selenium-2-aka-selenium-webdriver)

Read more about how to use them for example with capybara here:
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

Comment: Thank you, but isn't Capybara used for testing? I was looking for something for interacting with websites in production mode.. not testing..

Comment: Yes capybara is usually used for testing, I just linked the drivers used in capybara for further reference.

Comment: And theres this guy who is using it with mechanize for something similar to what you want http://www.chadcf.com/blog/using-capybara-javascript-capable-replacement-mechanize

Answer (score 1):

You can try [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) with watir to hide browser. Your code would look something like this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, profile: profile
browser = Watir::Browser.new driver

browser.goto "http://example.com"
browser.wait_until do
  browser.text_field(name: 'login').set("email@example.com")
  browser.text_field(name: 'password').set("secret")
  browser.button(name: "Sign in").click
end

# etc...

browser.close
headless.destroy
```